# Chmod 777 files and folder. Still not viewable?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, permissions, chmod

I have a few pdf files in my /images folder on my website. All images are viewable on the site and working fine, but I can't get to the pdf files. I get a 404 error.

When I move the files to /downloads, they work fine.

There are no .htaccess files in /images or /downloads.
All file permissions are 777.
All folder permissions are 777.

I would prefer NOT having to move all non image files out of the folder and then making redirects/rewrites for the new location.

Is there something besides permissions that could be preventing me from viewing the files?

Comment: 404 is not a permission problem. Post your apache configuration and the (relevant) tree of your filesystem (e.g. `find /var/www`).

Comment: relevant tree:
  public_html/images
  public_html/downloads

What specifically in the apache conf? Its like 300 lines spit out from cpanel....

Comment: sorry the tree is actually /home/woodheat/public_html/images

I have added to the Virtual Host this:
<Directory "/home/woodheat/public_html/images">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: Byron Claiborne: just c/p your entire apache configuration on something like pastebin.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a .htaccess file in the images folder that prevented anything except image files from being accessed.

The problem was further compounded by settings in Apache conf that prevented .htaccess files from being returned in a search so I was unaware of the files existence.

Thanks,
Byron

Answer (score 0):

I am going on a limb here, but it may have something to do with the `content-type` associated with the file. You may need to add `application/pdf` as a supported MIME type in your Apache config to allow pdf files outside of the download directory...

Comment: They are viewable in every folder except /images. Also, yes, I have checked the MIME types and pdf's are in there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just set up a wrong tree path in your webserver, double check it.
If you can still open any files on your server, check its path in your browser, combine it with your webserver path, then surely you can fix it correctly.